# 13 interface Color<T extends ColorParam = ColorParam> {

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

everytime I run **ng serve** on my application I get this error.

ERROR in node_modules/@types/color/index.d.ts:13:40 - error TS2716: Type parameter 'T' has a circular default.

```
13 interface Color<T extends ColorParam = ColorParam> {
```

Comment: How did you define `ColorParam`?

Comment: type ColorParam = Color | string | ArrayLike<number> | number | { [key: string]: any };

Comment: So a `ColorParam` can be a `Color`, so you can have `Color<Color<Color<Color<Color<Color<Color<Color<Color<Color<Color<Color<Color<Color<Color<Color<Color<Color<Color<Color<Color<Color<Color<Color<Color<Color<Color<Color<Color<Color<Color<Color<Color<Color<Color<Color<Color<Color<Color<Color<Color<Color<Color<Color<Color<Color<Color<Color<Color<Color<Color<Color<Color<Color<Color<Color<Color<Color<Color<Color<Color<Color<Color<Color<Color<...>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>`. There could be `Color<...>` all the way down. No end of the rainbow.

Comment: Please consider editing the question to include a [mcve] as described in [ask].  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE and demonstrate your issue and only your issue, including any use cases you have (since the intended use of `Color` and `ColorParam` have bearing on what suggestions you should receive).  Good luck!

Comment: Please note that [I cannot reproduce your error](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsA26oB4AqyEAHpCACYDOaWOACnFHALbIC8N2UDTzAfMgDeyAL4AoMAE8ADigxceLdpxzIAPskpgooAObrkAQShNJAGWABrCLhABXZgCNoAjfafQDwgNrXJALk1tPQBdQLgQSVEgA), so you should try to give enough information relevant for others to reproduce it.  The answer may be as simple as "please upgrade to the latest version of TypeScript".